# How to make conditional path aliases?

Tags: 8, path-aliases

In Drupal 8 you can create path aliases by going to: admin/config/search/path/patterns/add

Which allows me to, for example, say that all content of type "blog_post" can have something like this:

```
/blog/[category]/[title]
```

The problem is, I want the TOP path to be different, depending on the category. Specifically, I want any blog post that has the category = Competition, to have:

```
/competitions/[title]
```

While still being able to have

```
/blog/[category]/[title]
```

I can't seem to get this going. Is there a way to do this? I tried creating another aliases but I don't think there is any path I can specify that will give me this?

Answer (score 3):

### Solution 1: Without code

- Configure a taxonomy vocabulary named *Blog category* to manage blog categories.
- Configure *Blog category* aliases to `/blog/[term:name]`.
- For the *Competitions* term, override the URL alias to `/competitions`.
- Configure a taxonomy term reference field (preferably single value) on the *Article* content type. Say, the field name is `field_category`.
- Configure the *Article* path pattern as `/[field_category:entity:url:path]/[node:title]`.

This is somewhat like what gapple has mentioned above.

### Solution 2: With code

- Configure a taxonomy vocabulary named *Blog category* to manage blog categories.
- Configure a taxonomy term reference field (preferably single value) on the *Article* content type. Say, the field name is `field_category`.
- Configure the *Article* path pattern as `/blog/[field_category:entity:name]/[node:title]`
- Use `hook_pathauto_pattern_alter()` or `hook_pathauto_alias_alter()` to change the path pattern depending on the `$context`.

This is what I did for my problem. This way, you can choose whatever alias you want for your taxonomy term.

Answer (score 2):

A solution I've implemented for a potentially similar problem in the past, however it only works if the Category taxonomy is exclusive to the blog content type:

1. Set the pattern for 'category' taxonomy terms to `/blog/[name]`
2. Override the alias for the Competition term to be `/competitions`
3. Set the pattern for the blog nodes to reference their category's path.
   This should be something like `[test_term_reference:entity:url:path]/[title]` (or `[test_term_reference:entity:0:url:path]/[title]` if category is multi-value)

---

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2493559 for where Token module implemented tokens for referenced entities.